# Vagrant won't forward ONLY port 80

Tags: macos, centos, firewall, vagrant, portforwarding

I have port forwarding set up for vagrant

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centOS"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 80
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8443, host: 8443
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8443, host: 9443
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8445, host: 8445
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8000 
  config.vm.hostname = "www.vagrant.com"
end
```

Port 80 is open from my vagrant virtual box

```
[vagrant@www ~]$ nmap -sT 0.0.0.0 -p 80 

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-02 22:25 UTC
Nmap scan report for 0.0.0.0
Host is up (0.000063s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
```

But it is closed from my host machine

```
Ben-Fischer:~ bfischer$ nmap -sT 0.0.0.0 -p 80 

Starting Nmap 6.25 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-02 17:38 CDT
Nmap scan report for 0.0.0.0
Host is up (0.000086s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http
```

Nothing else is listening on port 80 on my host machine

```
Ben-Fischer:~ bfischer$ sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:80 | grep LISTEN
[no output]
```

Iptables are off and so is my mac firewall

```
[vagrant@www ~]$ sudo service iptables stop
```

And all of the other forwarded ports work fine (8443,9443,8445,8000)

The box is an image from vagrant, centOS 6.3 with chef.

So... why can't I connect to port 80 from my local machine?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I don't think you can forward to host ports < 1024, unless VirtualBox is run as `root` on the host.

The [VirtualBox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) says this about NAT mode limitation:

> Forwarding host ports < 1024 **impossible**:
>
> On Unix-based hosts (e.g. Linux, Solaris, Mac OS X) it is not possible to bind to ports below 1024 from applications that are not run by root. As a result, if you try to configure such a port forwarding, the VM will refuse to start.

These limitations normally don't affect standard network use. But the presence of NAT has subtle effects that may interfere with protocols which normally work. One example is NFS, where the server is often configured to refuse connections from non-privileged ports (i.e. ports below 1024).

Comment: I tried starting VirtualBox with sudo virtualbox but I'm getting the same results.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I think that's because vagrant runs a headless instance of virtualbox and it won't run it as root.

Comment: Note that, at least as of Vagrant 1.4.1, the VM will start, even if `autocorrect` is set to true, but the port will simply not forward.

Comment: The VirtualBox refers to Unix-based hosts, but I have the same problem with Windows host and a Windows VM as well. Port 80 doesn't work, port 8800 or 8080 works fine.

Answer (score 24):

Terry's answer correctly diagnosed the problem.  Here's my solution:

Instead of running VirtualBox as root, port forward twice.  Set up vagrant to forward host: 8080 to guest: 80.  Combine that with some port forwarding rules on the host machine (using the ipfw utility) so that 80 goes to 8080 on the host machine. Then 8080 will get sent back to 80 on the guest machine.

Seems convoluted but this article describes the setup more clearly
http://www.dmuth.org/node/1404/web-development-port-80-and-443-vagrant

Comment: The unavailable link is available here (although it's probably out of date) https://web.archive.org/web/20181207164919/http://www.dmuth.org/node/1404/web-development-port-80-and-443-vagrant

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to using ipfw, which I did not have installed on my machine (Arch Linux), is SSH.

If you are running the webserver on port 80 on the guest then you can run a port forward in the background using SSH.

```
sudo ssh -p 2222 -gNfL 80:localhost:80 vagrant@localhost -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE:**

`ipfw` has been deprecated as of OS X Mavericks. You should be using `pfctl` instead. I wrote an article which goes into detail on how to accomplish this here:

http://salvatore.garbesi.com/vagrant-port-forwarding-on-mac/

---

<s>**On Mac OS X via Terminal:**</s>

> > sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to me 80 in

*This will redirect all incoming traffic on 127.0.0.1:80 to 127.0.0.1:8080*

Comment: @SinanEldem I posted an article about this that's probably worth reading. Apparently `ipfw` has been deprecated as of Mavericks and you should probably use `pfctl` which is what I wound up going with in the  end. I have the port automatically bind whenever I run vagrant up. I edited the post to include the article.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a bridge adapter and then point to the local ip address instead of using localhost.
Since this can vary according to the host (like local ip address in use and so on) I'll put everything into an external `config.yml` file.

```ruby
# ...

require 'yaml'

current_dir    = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
configs        = YAML.load_file("#{current_dir}/config.yml")
vagrant_config = configs['config'][configs['config']['use']]

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

# http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/networking.html
config.vm.network vagrant_config['vm']['network_type'],
    ip: vagrant_config['vm']['network_ip'],
    bridge: vagrant_config['vm']['network_bridge'],
    virtualbox__intnet: vagrant_config['vm']['network_intnet']
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", 
    guest: 80, 
    host: vagrant_config['http_server']['host_port']

# ...
```

Follows the config.yml file:

```yaml
config:
    use: "public"
    private: # this is the old configuration that doesn't let you forward on port 80
    vb:
        cpus: 2
        memory: 4096
    vm:
        network_type: "private_network"
        network_ip: "192.168.33.10"
        network_intnet: true
        network_bridge: ""
        synced_folder: "/home/francesco/whatever/vagrant-synced-folder"
    http_server:
        host_port: 8080
    public: # here follows the new bridged configuration that let you use port 80!
    vb:
        cpus: 2
        memory: 4096
    vm:
        network_type: "public_network"
        network_ip: "192.168.1.123"
        network_intnet: false
        network_bridge: "eth0" # or whatever is your adapter name!
        synced_folder: "/home/francesco/whatever/vagrant-synced-folder"
    http_server:
        host_port: 80
```

Then just go to `http://192.168.1.123:80/` :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Port forwarding for Vagrant on OSX: ipfw is depreciated

Further to @sgarbesi's response, ipfw was indeed depreciated as of OS X Mavericks. Unfortunately I couldn't access the solution he posted as the link appears to be broken.

He is credited in the solution described here, however: https://www.danpurdy.co.uk/web-development/osx-yosemite-port-forwarding-for-vagrant/

I'm pasting the solution here for completeness, in the hope that it helps someone:

#### Set up port fowarding on the VM

Add the following to your Vagrantfile, as per the [Vagrant documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html):

`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 4443`

#### Install Vagrant Triggers

To install vagrant-triggers you should navigate in a terminal window to the folder where your Vagrantfile is kept and run the following command:

`vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers`

#### Use Vagrant Triggers to automatically enable port forwarding

Add the following to your Vagrantfile:

```
config.trigger.after [:provision, :up, :reload] do
      system('echo "
        rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080  
        rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 4443
  " | sudo pfctl -ef - > /dev/null 2>&1; echo "==> Fowarding Ports: 80 -> 8080, 443 -> 4443 & Enabling pf"')  
  end

  config.trigger.after [:halt, :destroy] do
    system("sudo pfctl -df /etc/pf.conf > /dev/null 2>&1; echo '==> Removing Port Forwarding & Disabling pf'")
  end
```

This binds ports 80 and 443 to ports 8080 and 4443 respectively on Vagrant Provision, up and reload and removes it on halt or destroy. Note that pf is not enabled by default on OSX so we pass the -e flag when we add the rules to enable pf and the -d flag to disable it again when we remove the port forwarding.

Answer (score -1):

You can config port forwarding into VirtualBox:

> Your VM -> Settings -> Network -> Advanced -> ports forwarding

Here you can add ports that you need.